# Avoid querying twice for the same thing ? (in page and in its master page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a website with a page which looks like that :

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MyPageService service = new MyPageService();
    private User user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user = service.CurrentUser;

        if (user != null)
            DoSomethingUsingUser();
    }
}
```

My problem is the master page also needs to get back the current authenticated user in order to update its content (user money amount, new messages etc.), and perform some actions such as log out.

```
public partial class MyMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private User user;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        user = ...;
        UpdatePage();
    }

    private void UpdateMoney()
    {
        if (user != null)
            _Money.Text = "Money: " + user.Money;
    }

    private void UpdateNewMessages()
    {
        _NewMessage.Visible = (user != null) && user.HasNewMessages();
    }

    private void UpdatePage()
    {
        UpdateNewMessages();
        UpdateMoney();
    }

    protected void _LogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So my question is since "MyMasterPage" is "MyPage"'s master page, is there a clean way to share the current user object between the page and its master page, rather than query the database for it twice, once in page and once in master ?
Or should I query twice anyway ?

Thanks a lot !

***In case it might be useful :***

Here is the service used in MyPage :

```
public class MyPageService : CommonAuthenticatedService
{
    public MyService()
    {
    }

    ...
    SomeSpecificMethods();
    ...

    # region Override

    // Loads user resources specifically required for MyPage page
    protected override IQueryable<User> LoadUserResources(DbSet<User> users)
    {
        return users
            .Include(x => x.SomeProperty1)
            .Include(x => x.SomeProperty2)
            .Include(x => x.SomeProperty3)
            ...;
    }

    # endregion Override
}
```

And the common service, used in every service which needs authenticated user :

```
public abstract class CommonAuthenticatedService
{
    public User CurrentUser { get; private set; }
    protected UserRepo userRepo = new UserRepo();

    public CommonAuthenticatedService()
    {
        SetCurrentUser();
    }

    protected abstract IQueryable<User> LoadPlayerResources(DbSet<User> users);

    private void SetCurrentUser()
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            Guid? currentUserId = userRepo.GetCurrentId();

            if (currentUserId.HasValue)
            {
                DbSet<User> users = userRepo.GetDbSet();

                CurrentUser = LoadUsersResources(users)
                    .SingleOrDefault(e => (e.Id == (Guid)currentUserId));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no great knowledge of old asp, but shouldn't it be cached inside session? That way, you would avoid a call to the DB everytime the user accesses a page

Comment: Define a public property in `MyMasterPage` which will hold `User`. Then from content page use that property to get the user. You will have something like this in content page - `var user = (Page.Master as MyMasterPage).CurrentUser`, assuming CurrentUser is public property on the master page that will return `user`.

Comment: Thanks for reading me and for commenting ! I'm pretty new in asp.net but Jean-Philippe idea sounds pretty great, I'l try this ! If this does not do the trick I will then try Michael solution, which seems good too. Thanks !
Jean-Philippe, could you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it ?